# SSH Tunneling only accepted on some ports

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I'm working with Server running Ubuntu Server 14.04. I use `Plink` to request some reverse tunnels from a remote computer to the server.

For some ports that works just fine, but for most ports it seems like the server refuses the request. It works for ports that are regularly used for this application like the VNC port `5900`, the RDP port `3389`, and the MySQL port.
It also seems to work for `5901-5999`. I would like to get the other ports working too, but I can't figure out why it refuses those forwarding requests.

There are no custom rules in the IPtables and it is an almost clean install.

Answer (score 1):

On the local side, ports under 1024 are privileged and you would need to run `ssh` as root to reverse forward a remote port to them.

On the remote side, `sshd_config` can lock down specific tunneling ports with the `PermitOpen` keyword.  Also, you can not reverse forward a priviliged remote port without privileges on the remote machine (ssh as root@remote_machine).

A possible workaround is using `nc` or `socat` to forward ports without escalating `ssh` privileges or changing `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Sorry I forgot about this thread. It turned out that, (altough the network administrator assured me that this was not the case), all the traffic was just going through a firewall...